# What is the meaning of "Hero unit"?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, language-history

What does the term "hero" mean and why was it used to name a site/page's "primary message"?

Specifically I'm wondering if the term "hero" or phrase "hero unit" is some common nomenclature used in web design that I've managed to miss.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The term "hero" is used by movie/television prop designers; a "hero prop" is the one built for closeups. It's got the most detail, and is most realistic. It's the best version of a prop, the most important one. I have always assumed that’s where they got the term from.