# What does hero unit mean?

Tags: css

I just generated an app using Yeoman and in the view there is a div with the class `hero-unit`. I figure this is a pretty popular question and Google doesn't get me anything remotely relevant other than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867137/twitter-bootstrap-what-is-the-meaning-of-hero) also on StackOverflow, which I wish had more discussion.

So, what does it mean?

Comment: Does it really matter? (And is the explanation in the duplicate not sufficient?)

Comment: It's from Bootstrap 2's [Typography](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#typography) -- "*A lightweight, flexible component to **showcase key content** on your site.*" Bootstrap 3 has since renamed it as [Jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron).

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'd like to know and I'm not sure of the validity of the duplicate, the gentleman who responded said he's assuming.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Awesome, I didn't see that. Though that doesn't answer my question and I'm still left wondering why pick this term in the first place?

Comment: @mattvleming Probably the only people who know for certain are the authors. It's just a name they chose for it. But, for the record, it was [added by `mdo`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/72899a4ee8f9c3b75ba5e015d6c88f5154705c62) before [`1.1.0`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v1.1.0/lib/patterns.less#L255-L272).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Awesome find (another one!), I just posted a comment asking why he picked it, why not right?

Comment: @mattvleming did her every tell you why? Still curious in 2018.

Comment: [hero image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image) wikipedia entry could help figuring a possible "meaning" of hero unit as well, that should be intended generically as a prominent section of content primarily used to generate visual impact about something.

Comment: This is on google and it makes me sad...

Comment: Page dedicated to explanation, insights and use-cases https://www.optimizely.com/optimization-glossary/hero-image/